# Receiving error that a function is "not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

I am working on a bubble sort in C++ and I am having issues passing a value as a pointer.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int values[9] = {7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5};

void printValues(){
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
       cout<<values[i]<<endl;
}


void sortValues(){
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            if (values[i]>values[j]){
                swapValues(values[i], values[j]);
                printValues();
            }
        }
    }
}

void swapValues(int *i, int *j){
    int temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Before: " <<endl;
    printValues();
    sortValues();
    cout << "After: " <<endl;
    printValues();

}
```

When I run the code as is, I receive the error message: 'swapValues' was not declared in this scope.  I have tried changing the things around where I added asterisk (swapValues(values[i], values[j]);) but that just seemed to have made things worse.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: (This has nothing to to with bubble sort or pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swapValues() function must be declared before the sortValues() function.

Comment: This worked for me!  Thanks for your help.  Weirdly enough when I tried this before while still writing the program, I received an error regarding i and j not being defined in swapValues().  Any idea why that would happen?

Answer (score 5):

Functions need to be (at least) declared before they are used. Move the definition of `swapValues` above `sortValues` or write a declaration:

```
void swapValues(int *i, int *j);

void sortValues(int *i, int *j) {
// etc...
```

Also, as `swapValues` takes pointers, you need to take addresses of the elements of the array when you call it:

```
swapValues(&values[i], &values[j]);
```

Alternatively, because arrays decay to pointer to their first element, you can use pointer arithmetic instead of indexing:

```
swapValues(values+i, values+j);
```

Comment: Also fix :`swapValues(&values[i], &values[j]);`

Answer (score 1):

Change the program where you are calling swapValues to

```
swapValues(&values[i], &values[j]);
```

Comment: This is the second issue, which comes once the OP's error is resolved

Comment: @Nick: you need to change this along with the declaring the prototype of your swapValues() which has explained below post. Below post contains the complete explanation about your problem.